# Using VueJS to create a embeddable Chat Widget for websites

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm building a product similar to Intercom live chat widget (tawto, drift, crisp etc). Basically, what it will do is add a widget to users website and then render a chat box (in simple words). I'm planning to use VueJS for the entire project.

So here are my thoughts.

We provide users an embeddable js snippet. What it will do is add a div to the body with id = "app" (or something like that). Then the same script will inject VueJS compiled code. Will also add some external scripts like socket io, some CSS libraries etc.

Here are my concerns:

1. Should I build the project using CDN vue.min.js or the CLI with compiled codes? (I'm comfortable with CLI)
2. I need to isolate my CSS libraries from users website, that possible with 'scoped' style in VueJS right?
3. If I use CLI version, will it work in a subdomain, inner pages, and links? Unlike a full website, I'm going to use VueJS to create a widget on the website

Answer (score 3):

I have used vuejs to create widget before so this is your answer:

1. You should build a normal project, import vue and compile it with all of your code to 1 file.
2. Yes
3. Yes
4. Yes

Comment: 1. We can do it in webpack right? compile everything to one?

Comment: Yes. What I mean is just 1 js file and 1 CSS file (it will create shorter snippet). With `vue-cli`, you should remove all `CommonsChunkPlugin`